# Allow only some check boxes to be checked. Loaded on page_load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am dynamically adding asp check boxes to my page based off of number of rows in my db table, by ID. Also the checkbox is being assigned an ID from the db table. I also two columns in my db table "numberOffered" and "numberAllowed".  My idea is on page load only allow the user to check say 3 of the 10 check boxes shown. I have removed a lot of the code I thought would be unnecessary. Thank you very much in advance.

```
For Each Arow As Object In ATable.Rows
    For Each Brow As Object In BTable.Rows
        If Brow(1) = a_ID Then
            If Brow(2) = b_ID Then
                Dim cbShown As Integer = Arow(5)
                Dim cbAllowed As Integer = Arow(6)
                Dim checkBox As New CheckBox()
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

checkBox.ID = Crow(0)
divcontrol.Controls.Add(checkBox)
```

EDIT:
Full Page_load sub

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not (Session("studentLoggedIn") Or Session("adminLoggedIn")) Then
            Routines.LogOut()
        End If

        If Session("adminLoggedIn") = True Then
            castVote.Enabled = False
            castVote.CssClass = "btnDisabled"
            Dim p As New HtmlGenericControl()
            p.TagName = "p"
            p.InnerText = "Vote button disabled. Only students may vote."
            adminMsg.Controls.Add(p)
        End If

        Dim ballot_ID As Integer = CType(Session.Item("ballot_ID"), Integer)
        Dim ballotName As String = CType(Session.Item("ballotName"), String)

        Dim ballotsAdapter As New eVoteTableAdapters.ballotsTableAdapter()
        Dim ballotsTable As New eVote.ballotsDataTable
        ballotsTable = ballotsAdapter.GetDataBy3getBallotsByID(ballot_ID)

        Dim sectionsAdapter As New eVoteTableAdapters.sectionsTableAdapter()
        Dim sectionsTable As New eVote.sectionsDataTable
        sectionsTable = sectionsAdapter.GetDataBygetsectionsByBallotID(ballot_ID)

        Dim candidatesAdapter As New eVoteTableAdapters.candidatesTableAdapter()
        Dim candidatesTable As New eVote.candidatesDataTable
        candidatesTable = candidatesAdapter.GetDataBygetCandidatesByballotID(ballot_ID)

        openBallotName.InnerText = ballotName

        Dim section_ID
        For Each row As Object In sectionsTable.Rows
            If row(1) = ballot_ID Then
                section_ID = row(0)
                Dim sectionName As New HtmlGenericControl()
                Dim sectionDescription As New HtmlGenericControl()
                Dim divcontrol As New HtmlGenericControl()
                Dim br As New HtmlGenericControl()
                divcontrol.Attributes("ID") = section_ID
                divcontrol.Attributes("runat") = "server"
                divcontrol.Attributes("style") = "border: solid;"
                divcontrol.TagName = "div"
                br.TagName = "br"
                sectionName.TagName = "h4"
                sectionDescription.TagName = "p"
                mainBallotDiv.Controls.Add(divcontrol)
                mainBallotDiv.Controls.Add(br)
                sectionName.InnerText = row(2)
                sectionDescription.InnerText = row(3)
                divcontrol.Controls.Add(sectionName)
                divcontrol.Controls.Add(sectionDescription)


                For Each Crow As Object In candidatesTable.Rows
                    If Crow(1) = ballot_ID Then
                        If Crow(2) = section_ID Then
                            Dim checkBox As New CheckBox()
                            Dim canImg As New Image()
                            Dim canName As New HtmlGenericControl()
                            Dim canBio As New HtmlGenericControl()
                            Dim rmImg As New Image()
                            Dim rmName As New HtmlGenericControl()
                            Dim rmBio As New HtmlGenericControl()
                            Dim canBytes As Byte() = Crow(6)
                            Dim canBase64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(canBytes, 0, canBytes.Length)
                            Dim rmBytes As Byte() = Crow(11)
                            Dim rmBase64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(rmBytes, 0, rmBytes.Length)
                            checkBox.ID = Crow(0)
                            canName.TagName = "h3"
                            canBio.TagName = "p"
                            rmName.TagName = "h3"
                            rmBio.TagName = "p"
                            canName.InnerText = Crow(4) & " " & Crow(5)
                            canBio.InnerText = Crow(7)
                            canImg.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString("data:image/png;base64,") & canBase64String
                            canImg.Height = 120
                            rmName.InnerText = Crow(9) & " " & Crow(10)
                            rmBio.InnerText = Crow(12)
                            rmImg.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString("data:image/png;base64,") & rmBase64String
                            rmImg.Height = 120
                            divcontrol.Controls.Add(checkBox)
                            divcontrol.Controls.Add(canImg)
                            divcontrol.Controls.Add(canName)
                            divcontrol.Controls.Add(canBio)
                            If row(4) = True Then
                                divcontrol.Controls.Add(rmImg)
                                divcontrol.Controls.Add(rmName)
                                divcontrol.Controls.Add(rmBio)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: I understand what you are asking but I am not sure exactly where you are encountering your problem, is it connecting to the db? or is it the logic of disabling the checkbox itself and where in the code to do that?

Comment: @Kevin I am having trouble disabling the remaining check boxes, after the allowed amount have been check. So if I can check 3 of 5, once I checked my 3rd the remaining 2 disable. I have my connection to db and retrieving my info just fine.

Comment: @mjw thank you for the edit recommendation.

Comment: Your sample is weird, you create a checkbox variable inside an if statement but use it outside. Your foreach variable are object, which seems like they would be datarow. You tag it SQL, are you looking for a query? Do you want this dynamic or just when the page loads?

Comment: @the_lotus I don't need a query I already have the data. I just need the logic to disable remaining check boxes after a certain number of them have been check. My sample is sloppy I do apologize, I just took parts out of my code that were relevant.

Comment: @JayyCodez do you want to do it server side or client side?

Comment: @the_lotus server side works fine. I believe. I will edit my post and add my whole page_load sub. Maybe that will help, don't judge me to badly lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want a variable (integer) for the amount of checkboxes allowed, then another variable for the amount of checkboxes currently checked, finally a List containing the name of each checkbox, (have all these variables as class fields)

then in your event handler something like

```
Sub Check_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

checked += 1        
        If checked >= NumberAllowedChecked Then
            For Each a As CheckBox In MyCheckBoxList
                   If Not CheckBox.Checked Then CheckBox.Enabled = False               
                Next
        End If
End Sub
```

I am not overly familiar with VB but I think this should set you on the right track on how to implement it for yourself

***Edit:*** you will want to add in logic for if a user unchecks a check box that it will subtract one from 'checked;